# deletion of a node in binary tree passing node by reference only

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to delete a binary tree, my program work as follows:

(1) It reads the number of nodes to be created in tree.

(2) It reads all those nodes.

(3) It print the tree formed by those nodes.

(4) It reads the node to be delete at terminal.

Until here everything works fine but when i try to delete the desired node then it gives segmentation fault error.

**Note: I have to pass the root by reference only (thats why i have kept two pointers for root in delete_tree_node(int delete_val, node  **root)).**

My approach to do so is:
I call recursively the function delete_tree_node() by left and right child in order to traverse the tree until i get the value of node equal to the value the node which user wants to delete.And once if i get that place then i free() that node.

My code to achieve this is: (which gives segmentation problem):

```
delete_tree_node(int delete_val, node  **root)//two "**" because i call by reference in function call    
{
 node*temp1;
 temp1=(*root);
if(delete_val==(*root)->freq)
   {    
     free((*root));    
     temp1=temp1->left;    
     (*root)=temp1;     
   }   

if(delete_val<temp1->freq)    
   { 
     delete_tree_node(delete_val,&temp1->left);    
   }
if(delete_val>temp1->freq)    
   {
     delete_tree_node(delete_val,&temp1->right);
   }    
}
```

It's function call is :

```
delete_tree_node(delete_val, & head);//I give reference
```

Could some one help me in knowing :

(1) Why it gives segmentation error.

(2) Is my logic is correct to delete the desired node ?, If not then could you please give me a piece of code to make as reference?

Comment: Review in a textbook how deletion of a node in a binary search tree is done. It's not so simple as you have programmed currently.

Answer (score 2):

> Why it gives segmentation fault?

Because you free the memory pointed by `*root` before you try to access the same memory in `temp1->left`.

Let's look at things closely :-

```
temp1 = (*root)
```

temp1 now holds the same memory address as (*root), i.e. both are some numbers that point to the same address. For the sake of clarity, let's assume that number to be '6'. So, both of them point to the memory address '6'. Note, they are not equal to the value at that address, but are just pointing to that.

Now, `free((*root));` tells the system that you are freeing the memory location pointed to by (*root), which in this case is 6. Once you free the memory, you lose access permission to that memory and next time you request it (through `temp1->left`), you get the segmentation fault.

I hope that clarifies what is causing the segmentation fault.

A cursory glance tells me that you could fix this by freeing (*root) at the end. In fact, the recursive call would be clearer that way, since you can describe it through this pseudo-code :-

```
delete left subtree
delete right subtree
delete root
```

I will not delve into the correctness of the logic as it appears to be a homework problem, and it'd be advisable that you solve that part yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot free the node and then access it. Try to move the free after the `temp1=temp1->left`.
Also, you must return once you found the correct node or path (or use else if):

```
delete_tree_node(int delete_val, node **root)
{
  node *temp1;
  temp1 = *root;
  if(delete_val == temp1->freq)
  {    
     temp1 = temp1->left;    
     free(*root);    
     *root = temp1;     
  }   
  else if(delete_val < temp1->freq)    
  { 
     delete_tree_node(delete_val, &temp1->left);    
  }
  else if(delete_val > temp1->freq)    
  {
     delete_tree_node(delete_val, &temp1->right);
  }    
}
```

Comment: I tried to do that but it still gives error. Is my logic to do correct ? Could you please give any piece of code to make as refernce?

Comment: oh, sorry, there is another mistake, assuming you don't have duplicate freq: add a return before each } of the ifs

Comment: Thanks it works fine except that it don't print the node element after the element to be deleted (I mean it just prints the element which are before the element is deleted not after that position)

Comment: for eg. If i have a tree 12 14 542 672 1012 and if i try to delete 672 and then i try to print it gives: 12 14 542 nothing after that

Comment: take a look here: http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Binary_search_tree/Removal or http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GaT8uMDtEZo or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree

Answer (score 1):

```
 temp1=(*root); // copying  the memory address of node to temp1   
 free((*root));    // your freeing the memory here of the node 
 temp1=temp1->left;    // the memory your accessing is already free'd hence segmentation fault occurs
```

try interchanging the two statements .

```
temp1=temp1->left;
free((*root));
```

regarding the reference for logic [check here](http://dev-faqs.blogspot.in/2012/03/remove-node-from-binary-search-tree.html)

Comment: i tried to read two pointer approac but i don't understan where the delete the node ? there is no delete at all http://dev-faqs.blogspot.in/2012/03/remove-node-from-binary-search-tree.html

Comment: you can't just remove a node as it will have dependencies on it like left child and right child. try tracing the algorithm you will understand it better. take a look at what happens when data is matched, they check if that node has children(you can't just leave the child nodes) `BinaryTreeNode **successor = getSuccessor(&(*node)->left); (*node)->data = (*successor)->data;
 remove(successor, (*successor)->data);`